# How should I split the dataset in the Keras data generator train-valid-test?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How should I  split the dataset in the Keras data generator `train-valid-test`?
Should I load the train folder as a train-valid subset and load the test folder ad the test to use with `model.predict(...).` or use `valid_generator` again?

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        class_mode='categorical')

valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        class_mode='categorical')

history =  model.fit(train_generator,
                     epochs=10,
                     validation_data=valid_generator,
                     verbose=1)
```

, Here the predict step

```
pred = model.predict(valid_generator)
```

Answer (score 1):

One usually needs multiple instances of `ImageDataGenerator` due to the requirement of data augmentation for training dataset, while the same `ImageDataGenerator` without augmentation can be used for both validation and test datasets (with their corresponding directory paths). After training the model, `model.evaluate_generator` can be used to evaluate the model performance on the test dataset. Here is a simple example for a given model and valid directories for datasets:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

#An ImageDataGenerator with augmentation to generate images for training dataset
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    shear_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './train_dir',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

#An ImageDataGenerator to generate images for both validation and test datasets
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './val_dir',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './test_dir',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

#compiling the model
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
    metrics=['acc'])

#Training
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    epochs=3,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=50)

#Evaluation on test dataset
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=50)
print('test loss:', test_loss)
print('test acc:', test_acc)
```

Comment: But if there are only `train` and `test` folders, I guess need to use subset on the `train` folder

Comment: @heaprc Sorry, maybe I am missing something, but is there any reason for not using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` instead? It has a `validation_split` parameter enabling loading two datasets from the same base directory.